# How can I get table height from PDF::Table?

Tags: perl, pdf

I want to create a pdf file in Perl that includes a table and text before and after the table. I use [PDF::API2](https://metacpan.org/pod/PDF::API2) and [PDF::Table](https://metacpan.org/pod/PDF::Table) modules for that. My problem that I can't figure out the height of the inserted table. So I don't know where to start the text below the table.

```
use PDF::API2;
use PDF::Table;

my $pdf = PDF::API2->new();
$pdf->mediabox('A4');
my $page = $pdf->page();

my $font = $pdf->corefont('Helvetica');
my $fontsize = 12;
my $x = 20/mm; # left and right edge
my $y = 280/mm;
my $textwidth = 210/mm - 2*$x;
my $height = $fontsize * 2;

my $text = $page->text();
$text->font($font, $fontsize);
$text->translate($x, $y);

$text->paragraph('line above table', $textwidth, $height);
$y -= $height;

my $table = new PDF::Table;
$table->table(
    $pdf,
    $page,
    [
        ["Cell 1", "Cell 2"],
        ["Cell 3", "Cell 4"],
        ["Cell 5", "Cell 6"],
        ["Cell 7", "content longer than one line - content longer than one line - content longer than one line - content longer than one line"],
    ],
    'x' => $x,
    'w' => $textwidth,
    'y' => $y,
    'h' => $y - 20/mm,
    font => $font,
    font_size => $fontsize,
);

my $table_height = $fontsize * 10; # this is just estimated - how can I get the right value?
$y -= $table_height;
$text->translate($x, $y);

$text->paragraph('line below table', $textwidth, $height);
```

How can I get the right table height? You can also suggest different modules if the problem can be solved with them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation for `PDF::Table` at https://metacpan.org/pod/PDF::Table#table() suggests that the `table()` method returns the final Y co-ordinate, so change your code to do `my ($final_page, $number_of_pages, $final_y) = $table->table(` instead of just `$table->table(` and your `$final_y` will tell you where the table ends.

This will also help you to handle the case where the table spans multiple pages.